# What advantages are there for Google to send images as Base64 rather than e.g. jpg

Tags: image, base64, webp

I noticed that Google's new page preview gets it's images using base64 rather than plain e.g. jpgs or png's

What are the advantages of doing this?

Can base64 encoded images be compressed better during transit?

Or perhaps cached better by the browser or caching proxy?

Is it so they can do one HTTP request and receive the image and information about the image in one hit?

Any other ideas?

[EDIT]

I've just had a thought, maybe it's so google can use their new image format

http://code.google.com/speed/webp/ without support from browsers?

However looking at the string returned (using the fiddler to intercept the http traffic), the string mentions "image/jpeg". Unless some images are returned in webp format.

Comment: What are you referring to?  "google" covers a wide range of sins.

Comment: It's google.com - in the results page click the little magnifiying glass next to the page titles. I'm not sure if everyone will see the feature (maybe i'm part of a random beta)

Comment: Base64 just encodes data in a 7 bit way. It's not an image format. The underlying data must still be encoded somehow - is it still .jpg/.png or something?

Comment: That's true, I'm guessing it's PNG/JPG underneath - and base64 for the transport (maybe using the data URI scheme)

Comment: I'm no expert in this area, but from what I've read base64 is commonly used not for compression but for compatibility with systems unable to properly support the usual approach to a problem.  One example I read about was the original email protocol, which didn't support anything except standard text -- to embed an image using that protocol meant you had to convert the image to raw-text; base64 was what was commonly used to achieve this.  Not sure what the actual need for it is in this case, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is a data URL that's received from the server as a JSON(-ish) package with some metadata. I presume that packaging both the image data and the metadata into a single request is worth it in terms of caching and performance.

Comment: Yeah, I agree - reducing it to one http hit per image/data makes allot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

The golden rule for performance is to reduce the number of connections to the server. By using a data URI (image data encoded as base 64), that round trip is reduced. Additionally, if the page is gzipped, then that base 64 data can still benefit from compression.

See http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html/